# Should memory be allocated using Malloc for this function? Does that cause a segmentation fault?

Tags: c, debugging

I wrote this pseudocode because I want to try to build a basic calculator that I am using within a greater program. It is as follows:

---

For each token `t`:

If `t` is an operator or a left bracket, push it on the operand stack.

Else if `t` is a right bracket:
Repeatedly pop the operand stack until you hit a left bracket. For each operator found:

- Pop the value stack twice to get the operands.
- Perform the operation on these operands.
- Push the result of the operation on the value stack.

Else `t` denotes a number.

Convert `t` to an integer, and push it on the value stack.
When you are out of tokens, repeatedly pop the operand stack until it is empty, performing each operation as before. At this point there should be one number on the value stack, which is the answer.

---

When I wrote the code however, it gives me a segmentation error. I know that is related to memory but I am not sure how to fix it or if memory needs to be allocated for this function.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
```

Not sure if this is written right or if it will throw an error?

```
int operandApplication(int a, int b, char op){
  if (op == '+'){
    return a + b;
    }
    else {
      return a * b;
      }
} 


int popValStack(int valstack[], int *top){
  int valdata = valstack[*top]; 
  *top = *top - 1;  
 return valdata;
}

void pushValStack(int valstack[], int *top, int value){
  *top = *top + 1;
  valstack[*top] = value;
  }

char *popOpStack (char *charstack[], int *top){
  char *chardata = charstack[*top];
  *top = *top -1; 
  return chardata;
}

void pushOpStack (char *charstack[], int *top, char *value){
  *top = *top + 1;
  charstack[*top] = value;
  }
```

Do I need to allocate memory in the following main function using malloc?

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]){ 

int i;
int valueStack[50];
int valcounter = 0;
int opcounter = 0; 
int l; 
int m;
char *opStack[50]; 
char *op;

for(i = 1; i < argc; i++){
```

I used string compare here because it seemed easier but not sure if it is helpful.

```
  char *t = argv[i];
  int s1 = strcmp(t, "[");
  int s2 = strcmp(t, "+");
  int s3 = strcmp(t, "x");
  int s4 = strcmp(t, "]");

  if(s1 == 0 | s2 ==0 | s3 == 0){
    pushOpStack(opStack, &opcounter, argv[i]); 
  } 

  else if(s4 == 0){ 

    char *S = popOpStack(opStack, &opcounter); 

    while (*S!= '[') { 
      int a = popValStack(valueStack,  &valcounter);
      int b = popValStack(valueStack, &valcounter);
      pushValStack (valueStack, &valcounter, operandApplication(a, b, *S));
    }
  }
  else {
    int x = atoi(t);
    pushValStack(valueStack, &valcounter, x);
  }
}

while (opcounter > 0){

  op = popOpStack(opStack, &opcounter);
  l = popValStack(valueStack, &valcounter);
  m = popValStack(valueStack, &valcounter);
  pushValStack (valueStack, &valcounter, 
  operandApplication(l, m, *op));
}

printf ("%d\n", valueStack[valcounter]);

}
```

Comment: Please pick one language. We also need to know the input you are using. It would be better to hardcode that rather than using command line arguments if you want others to potentially compile your code.

Comment: Can you give us an example of the inputs which are causing the segfault?

Answer (score 0):

There's no need for `malloc` in this program as written. Stack memory, normal variable declarations like `int i` or `int valueStack[50]`, lives until the function its declared in exits. So all the variables you declare in `main` will live until the program finishes.

On the other hand, if you were to try to return stack memory like so:

```
int *newStack() {
    int stack[50];
    return stack;
}


int *valueStack = newStack();
```

That would be a problem, the memory `stack` points to would be freed once `newStack` returns. `vauleStack` would be left pointing at deallocated memory which may be overwritten.

The rule of thumb is if you return a pointer it has to be `malloc`'d.

---

I can't reproduce your problem, but I can see where it could be going wrong. There are several places you could be walking off your stacks.

Because `valueStack` and `opStack` are fixed sizes, both `pushValStack` and `popOpStack` will walk off the end of the stack when `top` reaches 49 leading to a (wait for it) stack overflow.

```
int valueStack[50];
int valcounter = 0;
for( int i = 0; i < 50; i++ ) {
    pushValStack(valueStack, &valcounter, i);
}
```

(*It's 49 and not 50 because `top` is incremented before putting the value on the stack. This leads to an off-by-one error where in order to store anything in position 0 `top` has to start at -1.*)

Similarly, `popValStack` and `popOpStack` can walk off the back of the array leading to a stack underflow. Negative indexes work in C; they read memory before the pointer which is bad. Interestingly, this did not cause an error for me. YMMV.

One way to spot these sorts of errors is to throw in some `assert`s to check you're not walking out of bounds. An assert is an expression which you assume to be true. If it isn't, the program halts.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <assert.h>

// Here I put the stack size into a constant so it can be referenced by the asserts.
#define STACK_SIZE 50

int popValStack(int valstack[], int *top){
    assert( *top >= 0 );
    int valdata = valstack[*top]; 
    *top = *top - 1;  
    return valdata;
}

void pushValStack(int valstack[], int *top, int value){
    *top = *top + 1;
    assert( *top < STACK_SIZE );
    valstack[*top] = value;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){ 
    int valueStack[STACK_SIZE];
    int valcounter = 0;
    for( int i = 0; i < STACK_SIZE; i++ ) {
        pushValStack(valueStack, &valcounter, 1);
    }
}
```

Then instead of a mysterious segfault, you'll get a clear error.

```
Assertion failed: (*top < STACK_SIZE), function pushValStack, file test.c, line 26.
```

Asserts are handy to verify any assumptions and boundaries you have in your code.

---

Taking this a step further, we can improve the code and integrity of the stack by using a struct to collect together all the variables related to the stack in one place.

```
typedef struct {
    int *stack;
    size_t size;
    size_t top;
} IntStack;
```

(*I've used `size_t` here instead of `int` because it is guaranteed to be large enough to hold the size of the largest possible object, so it's appropriate for array indexes.*)

Then the IntStack can be passed around as a single unit. It knows its size and where the top is.

```
void IntStackPush( IntStack *stack, int value ) {
    assert( stack->top < stack->size );
    stack->stack[stack->top] = value;
    stack->top += 1;
}

int IntStackPop( IntStack *stack ) {
    assert( stack->top > 0 );
    stack->top -= 1;
    return stack->stack[stack->top];
}

#define STACK_SIZE 50
int main(){ 
    int values[STACK_SIZE];
    IntStack valueStack = { .stack = values, .size = STACK_SIZE, .top = 0 };

    for( int i = 0; i < STACK_SIZE; i++ ) {
        IntStackPush(&valueStack, i);
    }

    for( int i = 0; i < STACK_SIZE; i++ ) {
        printf("%d\n", IntStackPop(&valueStack));
    }
}
```

Note that we have to manually initialize the struct which can be error prone. Instead we can write a function to do that for us. Since we're returning a pointer from a function *now* we need `malloc`.

```
IntStack *IntStackNew( size_t size ) {
    // Allocate space for the struct.
    IntStack *stack = malloc(sizeof(IntStack));

    stack->top = 0;
    stack->size = size;
    // And allocate space for the stack.
    stack->stack = malloc( size * sizeof(int) );

    return stack;
}
```

And since we're allocating memory on the heap, we need to free it.

```
void IntStackFree( IntStack *stack ) {
    free(stack->stack);
    free(stack);
}
```

Now the stack can be used without knowing anything about its guts.

```
#define STACK_SIZE 50
int main(){ 
    IntStack *valueStack = IntStackNew(STACK_SIZE);

    for( int i = 0; i < STACK_SIZE; i++ ) {
        IntStackPush(valueStack, i);
    }

    for( int i = 0; i < STACK_SIZE; i++ ) {
        printf("%d\n", IntStackPop(valueStack));
    }

    IntStackFree(valueStack);
}
```